# Stack pointer set correctly but call not working

Tags: assembly, msp430, stack-pointer

I'm using TI Code Composer Studio for the MSP430F1232.
Starting from a template in assembler, a call to a routine doesn't work but when I put the routine directly in the code,it works. Why does the call won't work?

```
;generated code, the watchdog is stopped and the stack pointer is set correctly
RESET       mov.w   #__STACK_END,SP         ; Initialize stackpointer
StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW|WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Main loop here
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            mov.b   #0FFh,P1DIR
            mov.b   #0,P1OUT
$1
            call    delay

            xor.b   #001h,P1OUT
            jmp     $1

            .newblock ;reuse local labels
delay       push    r14
            mov     #1000,r14
$1
            dec     r14
            jne     $1
            pop     r14
            ret
```

Comment: Not work how; what happens when you single-step with a debugger?  Fault with some kind of exception?  That's an important part of your [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the problem with a similar micro (MSP430FR2433).
It turned out that the addressing mode was wrong.
With other microprocessor types, we use

```
call MySubroutine
...
MySubroutine:
```

For the MSP430 and similar, we should use

```
call #MySubroutine
...
MySubroutine
```